# I need ideas for shadow/darkness magic powers?

Tags: magic

I want to create a character that can use shadow/darkness magic and I don't want him to be too overpowered. Every mage draws power from a source. All elemental magic users draw their power from air, earth, sun, moon, sky, water, plants/life at the cost of their mana(vital energy or life force) and stamina.

Other mages draw power using someone else's life force or the life around them, at the cost of their sanity/motions and aging factor.

Shadow magic user would draw power from another world. The void, shadowrealm and underworld. The restriction I created was that if he uses a particular spell too much the void or shadowrealm tries to take over his body, soul and mind.

Can you guys give me any ideas on the kind of spells or powers of the shadow magic users?
And also ideas to improve the system.
Thank You

Comment: This is far too broad and open-ended. WB.SE is for asking specific, answerable questions. Please go back and re-read our guidelines [here](/help).

Comment: Agreed, it may be good to craft a bit of your system/environment first, and then define your problem with a good, specific, description so that we can give you a good, specific answer.

Comment: This will be closed because it is too broad.  My suggestion - lay out what this magic is and why you think it runs the risk of being too overpowered.  Maybe there are aspects of the world you have built that make it so?  Lay out your situation so we understand how this kind of magic fits in and the problems you anticipate.

Comment: Raw idea fishing doesn't work well on a non-forum, Q&A site like Stack Exchange, without you (the OP or Original Poster, what does OP mean to you? It's oddly used in the question) providing details about your magic system, its strengths, its limitations, its context, etc. In other words, we need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).

Answer (score 1):

One of the more interesting shadow type magics I've come across are those that amplify insecurities in the opponent. They come with a built in limitation: anyone who is confident in who they are isn't affected.

For example, a spell to amplify someone's self doubt. It makes it so that the weak minded will go into an experience expecting to fail.

In Discworld the best practitioner of this is Esme Weatherwax, do takes great care to explain that it's not magic but "headology". She can just stare at someone and make them believe that they did something wrong. Add a touch of magic to it and you've got an interesting system I think...